# Do all trigonometric functions of HLSL use radians, and how to rotate image?

Tags: c++, hlsl

I searched the answer for the question in all available documentation: Microsoft, wiki and outside of manuals.
No place has answer for the question: *"Do all trigonometric functions of HLSL use radians?"*
I just found at Microsoft that parameters of functions must be:

> Each component should be a floating-point value within the range of -1
>   to 1.

But it doesn't say, if it is radians or grads...

For example, I have Vertex Shader and coordinates.
I need rotate picture ny 10°.
I pass 10 as parameter via constant buffer: `fzAngle` = 10.
I use transformation via polar coordinates system.
Is the following code correct?

**Vertex Shader**

```
float fzRadAngle = radians(fzAngle);
float2 ptPos = input.Pos.xy;
float polarAngle = atan(ptPos.y / ptPos.x);
float polarRadius = sqrt(pow(ptPos.x, 2) + pow(ptPos.y, 2));
polarAngle += fzRadAngle;
ptPos.x = polarRadius * cos(polarAngle);
ptPos.y = polarRadius * sin(polarAngle);

output.Pos.xy = ptPos.xy;
return output;
```

**UPD** So what about rotation... Even if I don't rotate, but just transfer between coordinates systems, I get image out of range (it disapears from target texture)

```
float fzRadAngle = radians(fzAngle);
float2 ptPos = input.Pos.xy;
float x = ptPos.x;
float y = ptPos.y;
float phita = atan(y / x);
float ro = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
x = ro * cos(phita);
y = ro * sin(phita);
ptPos.x = x;
ptPos.y = y;
output.Pos.xy = ptPos.xy;
return output;
```

And as I see, the problem in radius calculation, thus if I ommit `ro`, I get image back as it was:

```
float fzRadAngle = radians(fzAngle);
float2 ptPos = input.Pos.xy;
float x = ptPos.x;
float y = ptPos.y;
float phita = atan(y / x);
y = x * tan(phita);
ptPos.x = x;
ptPos.y = y;
output.Pos.xy = ptPos.xy;
return output;
```

**UPD**

I found some interesting things.

Coordinate system:

```
[-1, 1, -1, 1]
```

In case of this code, picture don't changing:

```
float2 ptPos = input.Pos.xy;
float x = ptPos.x;
float y = ptPos.y;
float phita = atan(y / x);
float ro = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
y = x * tan(phita);
ptPos.x = x;
ptPos.y = y;
output.Pos.xy = ptPos.xy;
return output;
```

In this case it disapears:

```
float2 ptPos = input.Pos.xy;
float x = ptPos.x;
float y = ptPos.y;
float phita = atan(y / x);
float ro = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
x = ro * cos(phita);
y = ro * sin(phita);
ptPos.x = x;
ptPos.y = y;
output.Pos.xy = ptPos.xy;
return output;
```

Even if I try to add/substruct 1 or 0.5 from end values of `x` and `y` this doesn't get image back to view field.

Here I just try to convert from Decart system to polar and back.

Comment: Basically everything always uses radians. Could you also link where they said -1 to 1 because that definitely doesn’t hold for trig functions

Comment: Mathematicians typically use radians.   C++ math/trig functions do too, and that is the norm for most programming languages.   The results of `cos()` and `sin()` functions are in the range -1 to 1, but that is not true for other trig functions (like `tan()`) or for inverse of trig functions.

Comment: That's what the `acos` page says and what the `asin` page should say (that page is wrong), but not what the `sin`, `cos`, and `tan` pages say. They all say "[in] The specified value, in radians".

Comment: This page for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-acos

Comment: See update of the question, please...